# Writing a pydantic object into a sqlalchemy json column

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I'm looking for a way to have a pydantic object stored in a sqlalchemy json column.  My attempts so far are being tripped up by a `datetime` field in the pydantic object.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

My first attempt was to simply serialise the result of `.dict()`.  But this doesn't convert datetime objects to strings so the serialiser falls over.  If I convert with `.json` then the result is a string and what's stored in the database is the json of a string not a dict.

```py
import sqlalchemy.orm
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

mapper_registry = sqlalchemy.orm.registry()
Base = mapper_registry.generate_base()


class _PydanticType(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sqlalchemy.types.JSON

    def __init__(self, pydantic_type):
        super().__init__()
        self._pydantic_type = pydantic_type

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value.dict() if value else None

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return self._pydantic_type.parse_obj(value) if value else None


class Test(BaseModel):
    timestamp: datetime


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    x = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    y = sqlalchemy.Column(_PydanticType(Test))


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///x.db', echo=True)
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
session.add(Foo(x=1, y=Test(timestamp=datetime.now())))
session.commit()
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: you can only store datetime as string in json. But when you read this json, you can convert it back with the same pydantic model

Comment: Edited Q: Amended _PydanticType process_xxx methods to handle case where field might be optional and value params could be None at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Eduard Sukharev describes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712221/453851), you can set sqlalchemy to use a different json encoder.

It's really well buried, but pydantic does give you access to it's own json encoders which handle things like datetime automatically

```py
import json
import pydantic.json


def _custom_json_serializer(*args, **kwargs) -> str:
    """
    Encodes json in the same way that pydantic does.
    """
    return json.dumps(*args, default=pydantic.json.pydantic_encoder, **kwargs)
```

... Then create a sqlalchemy engine with:

```py
create_engine(conn_string, json_serializer=_custom_json_serializer)
```

With that sqlalchemy will be able to handle `.dict()` results in pretty much the same way pydantic `.json()` works.

Note this doesn't work for classes with their own custom encoders.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in pydantic v2? I believe `pydantic.json.pydantic_encoder` is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use custom json serializer, like orjson, which can handle datetime [de]serialization gracefully for you.

Just pass a  serialization callback as `json_serializer` parameter to `create_engine()`:

```py
# orjson.dumps returns bytearray, so you'll can't pass it directly as json_serializer
def _orjson_serializer(obj):
    # mind the .decode() call
    # you can also define some more useful options
    return orjson.dumps(obj, option=orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC).decode()

create_engine(conn_string, json_serializer=_orjson_serializer)
```

For more options to pass to `orjson.dumps` see [orjson README](https://github.com/ijl/orjson#option).

Comment: This is what I did in the end, I forgot to come back to answer the question myself.  For the context of this question orjson is not so great since it's not certain to match pydantic. What is certain to match is `pydantic.json.pydantic_encoder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different python packages like orjson to configure json for pydantic model. eg

```
import orjson

class User(BaseModel):

username = str

    class Config:

         orm_mode = True 
         json_loads = orjson.loads
         json_dumps = orjson.dumps

         arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```